# How can I bind number values to CSS to create a timeline?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to position div elements on a timeline. Those element would be position according to an array and that array would be composed of floats from 0 to 1. 0 being the beginning of the timeline and 1, the end.

```
 let events = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 1]
```

I am using AngularCLI. I imagine I would iterate through my list with *NgFor, but then I just don't know how I could use my array's values to place my CSS elements on the right proportions.

Here's what I have in mind:

[image: timeline]

Comment: use a linechart or any line library from js, no point of reinventing the wheel

Comment: SVG would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can start with something like this (see the demo [on Stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-57880892?file=src/app/app.component.html)):

[image]

#### template

```html
<div #containerDiv class="container">
    <hr>
    <div *ngFor="let pos of [0,0.25,0.5,1]" 
        [ngStyle]="{'left.px': _getStyle(containerDiv,pos)}" 
        class="black-ball-container">
        <div>{{pos}}</div>
        <div class="black-ball">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### typescript

```js
_getStyle($div: HTMLDivElement, pos: number) {
  const rect: DOMRect | ClientRect = $div.getBoundingClientRect();

  return `${pos * rect.width}`;
}
```

#### scss

```css
$height: 10px;

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;

  max-width: 100%;

  hr {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: $height/4;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: $height/2;
    border: 1px solid;

    width: 100%;
  }

  .black-ball-container {
    position: absolute;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .black-ball {
    height: $height;
    width: $height;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: $height;
    border: 3px solid white;
  }
}
```

As per comments, there's also [this improved version on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-57880892-version-3)

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an idea on how I could iterates through multiple timelines without having them all on top of each other? Their elements are using position absolute and I don't know how I could work around that...

Comment: I haven't understood the scenario. You want a bunch of stacked timelines... is that right? If so, why don't you just turn it into a component?

Comment: I want a bunch of timelines, yes. But I don't want them to appear on top of each other. And they do because they are built with an absolute position... I'll probably have the same problem if I create a component with them.

Comment: Add a wrapper div setting `display: flex` and add `min-width: 100%;` to `.container` class. I'm not at the office right now and edit stackblitz is terrible on the phone, but take a look at this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-57880892-b

Comment: Right, although it'd make more sense to have them displayed in column with spacing between them --instead of inline, but when I put them in `flex-direction: column` I still have the same problem.

Comment: Well, I've put together a version a little bit improved (that recalculates when you resize the component for any reason: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-57880892-version-3

Comment: Can you figure out a way to put them one **under** each other ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199381/discussion-between-philx94-and-jpavel).